# Split Column depending on values and create new dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

Need you help regarding an import for a specific csv file and want to split the last column into other severals one depending on values inside ;)

csv exemple :

```
timestamp;event;resultid;docid;message
12/05/2021;search;86CE8D1E1D8B49B09B646F173E9E7A1A;pdf01;{valuea1|valueb1|valuec1/valued1/}
11/05/2021;search;1672D80B8619420997B4F2DC81872F67;pdf02;{valuea2|valueb2|valuec2/valued2/}
10/05/2021;search;7E353C85FC984B33861801676121133B;pdf03;{valuea3|valueb3|valuec3/valued3/}{valuea4|valueb4|valuec4/valued4/}
```

1. The last column values is inside {} caracters sometime there is more than 1 {} ...
2. First split value is | to be considered
3. Last is /

I almost know how to add new column by spliting value (for exemple with | splits caracter) but don't know how to add other line if specific values are in.

At the end I want to have a dataframe like this

```
timestamp;event;resultid;docid;valuea;valueb;valuec;valued
12/05/2021;search;86CE8D1E1D8B49B09B646F173E9E7A1A;pdf01;valuea1;valueb1;valuec1;valued1
11/05/2021;search;1672D80B8619420997B4F2DC81872F67;pdf02;valuea2;valueb2;valuec2;valued2
10/05/2021;search;7E353C85FC984B33861801676121133B;pdf03;valuea3;valueb3;valuec3;valued3
10/05/2021;search;7E353C85FC984B33861801676121133B;pdf03;valuea4;valueb4;valuec4;valued4
```

The two last line has been duplicated because last column had more than one {}

Comment: Can you share your current code, as well as more details on what the issue is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TRY:

```
df2 = (
    df1.assign(message=df1.message.str.replace('/', '|').str.replace('}{', '},{').str.split(',')
               ).explode('message')
)
df2[['valuea', 'valueb', 'valuec', 'valued']] = df2.message.str.lstrip(
    '{').str.rstrip('|}').str.split('|', expand=True)
```

Comment: Thanks so much :) I finally found another way ... I'll post the result soon (don't have the code at this moment)

Answer (score -1):

First you can use `.str.findall()` to find all values in each bracket and return them as a list.

Then you can use `|` syntax in `.str.split()` to split on multiple delimiters.

Finally use `drop` to drop `message` column

```py
df_ = df.assign(message=df['message'].str.findall(r'{(.*?)}')).explode('message')

df_[['valuea', 'valueb', 'valuec', 'valued']] = df_['message'].str[:-1].str.split('\||/',expand=True)

df_ = df_.drop(['message'], axis=1)
```

```
print(df_)

    timestamp   event                          resultid  docid   valuea   valueb   valuec   valued
0  12/05/2021  search  86CE8D1E1D8B49B09B646F173E9E7A1A  pdf01  valuea1  valueb1  valuec1  valued1
1  11/05/2021  search  1672D80B8619420997B4F2DC81872F67  pdf02  valuea2  valueb2  valuec2  valued2
2  10/05/2021  search  7E353C85FC984B33861801676121133B  pdf03  valuea3  valueb3  valuec3  valued3
2  10/05/2021  search  7E353C85FC984B33861801676121133B  pdf03  valuea4  valueb4  valuec4  valued4
```

To export to csv, you can use

```py
df_.to_csv('your.csv', index=False)
```